# catch inside the resolved promise doesn't change response.status()

Tags: javascript, promise

There are two data types to get using `promise` if they are found:

- The parent promise is rejected if the `card` is not found
- The second/child promise is expected to reject if the `terminal` is not found.

### Expected behavior:

a) If `card` is not found run:

```js
response.status(293);
response.end();
```

a) If `terminal` is not found run:

```js
response.status(292);
response.end();
```

### Code example

```js
getCard(cardID)
  .then((card: Card) => {
    getTerminal(terminalID)
      .then((terminal: Terminal) => {
        // do smth
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e); // log works fine
        response.status(292);
        // terminal does not exist
      });
    })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    response.status(293);
    // card doesn't exist
  })
  .finally(() => {
    response.end();
    // close connection
  });
```

### Problem:

The server returns `200` status in all cases other than `293`, the first `catch()`, which is the only one that is executed as expected.  I have a guess that it should be sequential promises, not child-parent based. How do we achieve that?

Comment: `terminal does not exist` correct, it's in the `.then` callback function - not sure why your comments are stating the obvious - did you need to access those values (like card and terminal)? try using async/await

Comment: @Bravo but it doesn't run `response.status(293)` just returns `200` every time the terminal doesn't exist.

Comment: that's weird - that suggests there's never an issue to respond with 292 or 293 status - maybe because the first .then doesn't return anything, the .finally is running too early - try `return getTerminal(terminalID)`

Comment: @Bravo consider your comment as an aswer! the issue is resolved. please write it as an answer.